# Strong inductive proof for recursive sequence given Explicit formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction, recursion

I am stuck on this

Show that the recursively defined sequence $a_n=2·a_{n-1}+3·a_{n-2}, a_1=-1, a_2=13$ has the explicit formula $〖a_n=3^n+4(-1)^n〗$

I can prove the base cases no problem but I keep getting stuck on the transformation

so I have $a_{k+1}=2·a_{k} + 3·a_{k-1}$

=$2(3^k+4(-1)^k)+3( 3^{k+1})+4(-1)^{k-1})$

=$2*3^k+8*(-1)^k+3*3^{k-1}+12*(-1)^{k-1}$

=$$2*3^k+8*(-1)^k+3^k- 12(-1)^k$$
=$$3*3^k-4(-1)^k$$

How do I get that -4(-1)^k to turn into +$4(-1)^{k+1}$?
Did I goof the alegbra somewhere?

Comment: Well, $(-1)\times (-1)^k=(-1)^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show:

$$3^{n}+4(-1)^{n} = 2[3^{n-1}+4(-1)^{n-1}] + 3[3^{n-2}+4(-1)^{n-2}]$$

Simplifying from the left we have:

$$2[3^{n-1}+4(-1)^{n-1}] + 3[3^{n-2}+4(-1)^{n-2}] = 2[3^{n-1}] + 8[(-1)^{n-1}] + [3^{n-1}] + 12[(-1)^{n-2}] =$$

$$=3[3^{n-1}] - 8[(-1)^{n-2}] + 12[(-1)^{n-2}] = 3^{n} + 4(-1)^{n-2} = 3^{n} + 4(-1)^{n-2}$$